# DTS .xls import;

Tags: sql, sql-server, xls, jet, dts

I'm new to DTS and wwas wondering if there was anyone who have had some experience with SQL on a server. I'm having an issue with the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. I've messed with the syntax and I've messed with it and I keep getting the same error. Here is what I'm working with as it stands right now:

```
INSERT INTO stores
 SELECT *
   FROM OPENROWSET(
                   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
                   'Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;DATABASE=L:\ITS\storedata.xls', 
                   'Select * FROM [storedata$]'
                  );
```

Does anybody have any idea? I can give more information if needed....

Comment: Please show the errors. Also have you installed the Access Connectivity Engine on the server that allows the OLEDB connection to Excel? Note the SQL Server has a import expert wizard that creates a DTS package for you too.

Comment: You know, I'm not sure if we have the Access Connectivity Engine or not. I was able to find a work around by just using an Update command.